# Setting the max and min trim length IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, avfoundation

I am selecting a video clip from the iPhone camera roll using UIImagePickerController within the AVFoundation framework, I have set it up so the user is able to adjust the length of the video by trimming it. Is there a way to set the maximum and minimum length the user is able to have the video as, for example I want the video clip to be a maximum length of 15 seconds and a minimum length also of 15 seconds.

What's the best way of going about doing this?

Answer (score 4):

```
`imagePickerController.videoMaximumDuration = 15.0f;` // limits video length to 15 seconds.
```

where imagePickerController is object of `UIImagePickerController`.

Using `videoMaximumDuration` method you can restrict length of video from both ways. Like if you are recording video an alert will popup saying you cannot record video more than 15 sec and if you are selecting any video file from your library, first it will check the length of your video if length is more than 15 sec. Again alert will popup saying video is larger than 60 sec but there will be two options i.e. use or cancel. If you select to use then it will crop the length of video upto 15sec from the beginning.

Comment: remember to set: imagePickerController?.allowsEditing = true

Answer (score 0):

UIImagePickerController has a property, videoMaximumDuration you can set.